# d3 line with very large number of data points

Tags: arrays, d3.js, audio

I am plotting a line in d3. It works well with a smaller number of data points. Once the number grows large, it fails with the following message :

```
error :  ƒ scale(x) {
    return (output || (output = piecewise(domain, range, clamp ? deinterpolateClamp(deinterpolate) : deinterpolate, interpolate)))(+x);
  }
```

Any pointers on fixing this problem ?

=== UPDATE ===

Thanks to the pointers and suggestions (in the comments below) I have now traced some problems.
I was doing a long search on the big data to find the extents - d3 doesn't like this :
this.xAxis.domain(d3.extent(xLimIn || [].concat.apply([], xVals)));

D3 also didn't like me shifting to the bottom :
this.xAxisG.call(d3.axisBottom(this.xAxis));

After commenting those out and manually putting in the domain limits, the browser ran out of memory !

There was a d3 transition, so I replaced it with a direct line plot. This same problem comes up.

It would seem that perhaps I should reduce the number of points in some sophisticated manner and give less points.

Any ideas for ways to decimate the data well ? Does d3 have these features in any way ?

Comment: from experiments d3 isn't handling more then roughly 96000 data points.

Comment: is it the limit on the length of the `d` argument of `path`

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I don't think that SVG/HTML will allow you to create an attribute of unlimited size. 96000 points means the `d` string is probably more than 1Mbyte. Try to limit the number of decimals by adding `.toFixed(1)` in the `d3.line` `x` and `y` accessors, to determine if the number of points is the problem or the attribute length

Comment: keep in mind you want to avoid having more than one pixel land on same x,y value ... adding more points to a line beyond this is counter productive

Comment: why don't you split your path in pieces of 10000 points

Comment: I added .toFixed to the line x and y accessors - nothing - then I console.log in the accessors. It isn't even making it that far through - this is a good clue!
It is a good point that if I have 1000 pixels, no point in showing more then 1000 points ... hmmm ... but how to interpolate - I thought d3 would do that for me ?
Nice idea to do a piecewise plot, I'll give it more thought.

Comment: Is there a simple way to split the path into pieces ?